# Return child type from a method on an abstract class or force two constructors on child with different parameters types

Tags: c#, .net, abstract-class, subclass

I have an abstract class TypedIdValueBase which has subclasses like UserId or ImageId.
I don't know how but I would like to have a Parse method (or a second constructor which is taking a string in parameter and not a Guid) and call it like that:

```
Guid valueG = Guid.NewGuid();

UserId userId1 = UserId.Parse(valueG ); //or new UserId(valueG )
ImageId imageId1 = ImageId.Parse(valueG ); // or new ImageId(valueG )

string valueS = "0f8fad5b-d9cb-469f-a165-70867728950e";

UserId userId2 = UserId.Parse(valueS ); //or new UserId(valueS )
ImageId imageId2 = ImageId.Parse(valueS ); // or new ImageId(valueS )
```

I would like to force each child class to have that method or a second constructor with a string parameter but I really don't know how to handle it.
I know about some "simple" answers like that:
[Abstract Method That Returns an Instance of Derived Class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9361401/abstract-method-that-returns-an-instance-of-derived-class)

Someone already linked my previous question to another answer without reading well what I want to do.
Pay attention to the type of the variables or parameters before to link and close it to an answer which is not answering the question. Thank you a lot.

The best I had was something like that:

```
string value = "0f8fad5b-d9cb-469f-a165-70867728950e";
UserId userId = (UserId)UserId.Parse(value); //or new TypedIdValueBase.Parse<UserId>(value)
```

Does anyone have an idea on how to do something like that ?

Here is the code without traces of my attempts:

```
public abstract class TypedIdValueBase : IEquatable<TypedIdValueBase>
{
    public Guid Value { get; private set; }

    protected TypedIdValueBase(Guid value)
    {
        if (value == Guid.Empty)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Id value cannot be empty!");
        }

        Value = value;
    }
}

public class UserId : TypedIdValueBase
{
    public UserId(Guid value) : base(value)
    {
    }
}

public class ImageId : TypedIdValueBase
{
    public ImageId(Guid value) : base(value)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand. Can you add a concrete sample of what you want to be able to write, like if it was a unit test, like if you usa a framework, with a constructor or a parse override but not both, with all cases you think, please.

Comment: You can't force derived classes to have a constructor with a specific argument list, unfortunately.  (Well, except for the `new()` constraint forcing parameterless.) Both your idea and the idea you linked to are implementations of the Abstract Factory pattern, which seems to be the closest thing to what you want. The link added generics to avoid casting to the derived type.  This [question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1393350/3791245) also point to using Abstract Factory.

Comment: @SeanSkelly Indeed, but we can "hide" some constructors as the default, and so prevent the use of same signature in childs by setting them private (or protected) in ancestor, to enforce the use of predefined parametized constructors, or any new.

Comment: @OlivierRogier Indeed!  You can't force derived classes _to have_ certain constructor signatures, but you can force them _not to have_ those signatures as you outline.  OP is asking about the former situation, though, and not the latter.

Comment: @SeanSkelly Now I understand the question, thanks. Thus it is impossible, as I know. Unless to rethink the design, perhaps using a builder design-pattern and/or reflexion to ensure the constructor signature match the required to throw exception at runtime if not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good day,

I found a way to have something like I wanted but I'm still not sure if it's a good thing to do.

With the code below I can do:

```
UserId userId = UserId.Parse(stringValue);
UserId userId2 = new UserId(guidValue);


public class UserId : TypedIdValueBase<UserId>
{
    public UserId(Guid value) : base(value)
    {
    }
}

public abstract class TypedIdValueBase<T> : TypedIdValueBase where T : TypedIdValueBase
{
    public static T Parse(string value)
    {
        var obj = (T)new object();
        obj.Value = Guid.Parse(value);
        return obj;
    }

    protected TypedIdValueBase(Guid value) : base(value)
    {
    }
}

public abstract class TypedIdValueBase : IEquatable<TypedIdValueBase>
{
    private Guid _value;

    public Guid Value
    {
        get => _value;
        protected internal set
        {
            CheckValue(value);
            _value = value;
        }
    }

    protected TypedIdValueBase(Guid value)
    {
        CheckValue(Value);
        Value = value;
    }

    private void CheckValue(Guid value)
    {
        if (value == Guid.Empty)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Id value cannot be empty!");
        }
    }

    public bool Equals(TypedIdValueBase other) => Value == other?.Value;

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(null, obj))
        {
            return false;
        }

        return obj is TypedIdValueBase other && Equals(other);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode() => Value.GetHashCode();

    public static bool operator ==(TypedIdValueBase obj1, TypedIdValueBase obj2)
    {
        if (Equals(obj1, null))
        {
            if (Equals(obj2, null))
            {
                return true;
            }

            return false;
        }

        return obj1.Equals(obj2);
    }

    public static bool operator !=(TypedIdValueBase x, TypedIdValueBase y) => !(x == y);
}
```